Distilling Example 4.2 in a linear analysis (functional analysis) text
Ok, believe it or not I'm in a graduate functional analysis class.
Let's take a moment to let that settle in.  Ok...
So, there is this example in a text on functional analysis.
The linear transformation $ T: C_F [0,1] \rightarrow F $ defined by
$$T(f) = f(0)$$ is continuous.
My understanding is that there are 5 equivalent ways of showing this based on a lemma in the text. I want to try to show it using a method similar to the example in text but slightly different. Can you check this, and maybe share one of the other ways to show this is so?
My proof is as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\left\|f(0)\right| &\leq \sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left\|f(x)\right\|\\
\left\|T(f)\right\| &= \left\|f(0)\right\|\\
||T||||f|| &= ||f(0)|| \leq \sup \left\| f(x)\right\|\\
\sup_{x \in [0,1]} \left\| f(x)\right\| &= \left\|f\right\|.
\end{align}$$
Thus, there exists a positive real number such that  $\left\|T(f)\right\| \leq k\left\|f\right\|$.
What are equivalent ways of showing this from, for example, the well-known lemma of continuous linear transformations?

What are the other four conditions? While I have seen a lemma such as this when I studied, I don't think there were as many as five conditions, and I only remember what one of the other conditions was. So, just so we're on the same page, and so the question is self-contained, what are the other conditions?

Hi @TheoBendit  Let  $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces  and let $T: X \rightarrow Y$ be a linear transformation. The following are equivalent:
(a) T is uniformly continuous;
(b) T is continuous;
(c) T is continuous at 0;
(d) there exists a positive real number k such that $||T(x)|| \leq k$ whenever $x \in X$ and $||x|| \leq 1$;
(e) there exists a positive real number k such that $||T(x)|| \leq k||x||$  for all $x \in X$

You've shown $\|Tf\| \le \|f\|$ for all $f$. This observation, or something markedly close to it, will be necessary to prove all the other equivalent properties. Certainly, combined with linearity, the other properties follow freely from this observation.
For example, to prove uniform continuity, I would let $\delta = \varepsilon$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, and observe that
$$\|f - g\| < \delta \implies \|f - g\| < \varepsilon \implies |T(f - g)| < \varepsilon \implies |Tf - Tg| < \varepsilon,$$
which proves uniform continuity, and uses the observation in the middle implication (and linearity in the final implication).
I could mince this a bit further, building the proof you presented of your observation. I would still let $\delta = \varepsilon$. I would then say, if $\|f - g\| < \delta$, i.e. $\|f - g\| < \varepsilon$, then $\sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |f(x) - g(x)| < \varepsilon$. So,
$$|f(0) - g(0)| \le \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |f(x) - g(x)| < \varepsilon.$$
But $|f(0) - g(0)| = |Tf - Tg|$, so $|Tf - Tg| < \varepsilon$, as required.
Note: it's the same basic ideas as your proof, rehashed. We could do similar treatments with the other conditions, and they'll end up much the same.
